# Is hybrid (Cordova) fast enough for simple cross-platform mobile game, or are there better alternatives?

Tags: android, ios, performance, cordova, cross-platform

I have a simple mobile game in mind that I would really want to make, but I can't decide on how to start. I would really want to make it run on Android and iOS, but I don't know how to accomplish that. I don't really want to use a game engine like Unity, since the game I have in mind is so simple that it would really be an overkill. The only thing I really need is a canvas to draw some shapes on.

So I was thinking about making it a hybrid app with javascript and Cordova, since I already know javascript and I'm comfortable with the javascript canvas. It's also good because you don't need to re-write code for both platforms, and thus programming will be faster and easier.

Now I am wondering if this is actually a good idea. I've never made a hybrid app before, and I don't really know if it's going to perform well.
I've read that hybrid apps run slower than native apps, but is this really that big of a deal? The game really has to run smooth, since it will be a fast-paced dodger style game.

How much slower are hybrid apps in comparison to native apps, and will it be fast enough for making a very basic 2d game run smoothly? Or are there better alternatives to hybrid, that won't make me have to re-write a lot of code for iOS and Android?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you've never done any of it before, then you will still have to solve a couple of problems here and there. I think you are not done just by implementing a canvas part. You will still want to add some UI, maybe some ads, in-app purchases, scoreboards etc. These topics are common in game development circles and there are many 3rd party tools to help you out. If you are really serious about game development, I think it is totally worth investing some time into Unity. It will pay back in a long run.

Comment: I see. Good point you made on ads, IAP, etc... Though, I feel like Unity is a bit overkill for the game I was thinking of. I don't need an engine at all.